# How to generate sin values to create an Image?

Tags: image, image-processing, trigonometry

I am creating an Image file for a sin function my computer science course.

But I do not know what is sin function at all !!

> Write a simple Java program that creates an image of the sin function.
>
> file format:  pgm (P2 / grey)
>
> file name:  out.pgm
>
> sin function:
>
> - width/domain/x:  [0..2Pi]
> - y:  real numbers [-1.0..+1.0]
>
> image:
>
> - width:  500 pixels ({0,..,499})
> - height:  250 pixels (repeat values from sin 250 times)
> - pixel values:  integers {0,…,255}

I am almost done with ASCII image creation and file format verification.

My only remaining problem is how to generate sin values?

I found Math.sin() and Math.PI but what then?

What is x?

What is y?

What is the domain here?

Comment: `x` is an angle in radians, form zero to 2*Pi and `y` is `sin(x)`. Does that help?

Comment: @RogerRowland OK, but why y: real numbers [-1.0..+1.0] what grantees that?

Comment: That's the output of the `sin` function - it *is* always within those limits. Maybe just put it in a spreadsheet and see what you get, then you'll have a better idea of what the plot should look like.

Comment: @RogerRowland I could not generate between 0 and 255 http://goo.gl/i5Prkc

Comment: Well, I'm reluctant to do it for you, you have to try to figure out the steps. You are generating an image 500x250 pixels, you want a sine curve in it. So, maybe you start with a black image, then you scale your x axis to 0..2Pi and your y axis to -1..+1 and for each x position, you make a pixel white at the y position that corresponds to the output of the sine function. Perhaps you can implement *something*, show some code, and ask a *specific* question.

Comment: @RogerRowland How about my Excel file, is in the right direction? You can view it without downloading it.

Comment: Your question says *"height: 250 pixels (repeat values from sin 250 times)"* so at any particular `x` position, you calculate `sin(x)` where `x` has been scaled appropriately in the range `0..2Pi`, then the value of `sin(x)` will be in the range `-1..+1` and you need to scale this to get a value between `0..255`. Then set all pixels in that column to that value. That's all I'm going to say for now - maybe you need to check with your tutor?

Comment: I am sorry made you mad :)

Answer (score 0):

In theory the sinus function maps every (real) value to a value between -1 and 1. Since you can not generate every real value with your computer, and since the sin function happens to be monotonic, repeting itself every 2*Pi, plotting the values between 0 and 2*Pi with a small increase each step will normally do.

This means:

x is an array like [0,0.001,0.002,...2*Pi]

y is sin(x)

Good luck with your asignment.

Comment: What is the domain?
width/domain/x: [0..2Pi]
How to map the width within 0...2?

Comment: x is your domain, it's "all" the numbers between 0 and 2Pi. Since you can not express all real numbers, you use an array whose elements gorw a bit with every step.

Comment: I am sorry, but still I am stuck. I have generated using excel but nothing appeared to be between 0 and 255!!
My file in SkyDrive: http://goo.gl/i5Prkc

Comment: It is a computer vision course and you are passionate of it :)
But how I am going to generate pixels from 0 to 255 from 0 ... 2pi?